# Extracting Binary Data from MSI

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I'm trying to extract the binary data from an MSI file using Powershell.
I can get any other piece of data, but I can't seem to extract the binary information.

```
$Query = "SELECT Data FROM Binary WHERE Name = 'bannrbmp'"
$View = $Database.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenView", "InvokeMethod", $null, $Database, ($Query))
$View.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", "InvokeMethod", $null, $View, $null)
$Record = $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Fetch", "InvokeMethod", $null, $View, $null)

$BinaryData = $Record.GetType().InvokeMember("StringData", "GetProperty", $null, $Record, 1)
```

It breaks on the final line, which leads me to believe that an issue exists with "StringData", but I could be way off target. Here is what the table looks like when opened up in Orca.
[image]

This code will successfully complete when extracting textual data as below.

```
$Query = "SELECT Component FROM FeatureComponents WHERE Feature = 'OrcaHelp'"
$View = $Database.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenView", "InvokeMethod", $null, $Database, ($Query))
$View.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", "InvokeMethod", $null, $View, $null)
$Record = $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Fetch", "InvokeMethod", $null, $View, $null)

$Data = $Record.GetType().InvokeMember("StringData", "GetProperty", $null, $Record, 1)
```

[image]

I couldn't seem to find anything on the web, if anyone is able to help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean _It breaks on the final line_? Is there an error to accompany this?

Comment: bannerbmp would (based on the *banner* and *bmp*) most likely be a bitmap. There are several others that include *ico*, which would indicate that they are icons. Why would you expect a bitmap or icon to support `StringData`? For that matter, why would you expect *any* binary data to automatically support `StringData`? It's not string data, it's binary data.

Comment: Take a look at Record.ReadStream. But honestly,  all this COM interop is pretty messy IMO and you aren't closing handles.  I can point you to other approaches if you are interested.

Comment: Matt It just thows an exception, doesn't say anything.
Ken, I'm trying to extract the icon from the exe inside the MSI, I understand it isn't string data. 
@ChristopherPainter I would love to know any approaches that I can use to solve this.

Comment: The other guys have got it right - binary data is extracted with a ReadStream type of API.

Answer (score 2):

This is a C++ code fragment that extracts a binary and writes it to disk. You could use it, or at least see the flow and the stream read. These are the basic Win32 API calls that all the scripting languages eventually call, no interop required. It would need some includes of stdio.h, windows.h, msiquery.h and packaging in a program or Dll to call - I don't know your C++ comfort level. This should work ok, even though I've not tested it recently.

```
PMSIHANDLE hDatabase;
PMSIHANDLE hBinaryView;
PMSIHANDLE hBinaryRecord;

//Get the handle to the active database. we need this to do view manipulation
UINT nr = MsiOpenDatabase ("some.msi", MSIDBOPEN_READONLY, &hDatabase);

//Get a view of the binary table based on the SQL Query
char sQuery []  = {"SELECT * FROM Binary WHERE Name='somebinary'"}; // Binary

nr = MsiDatabaseOpenView(hDatabase, sQuery, &hBinaryView);
if (nr!= ERROR_SUCCESS)
   return 1;

//MsiViewExecute Needs to to be called for MsiFetchView.
//We pass it null because the query above is as granular as we can get
//so we do not need to take it further by specifying an additional value.
nr = MsiViewExecute(hBinaryView, NULL);  
if (nr == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    //Fetch the view into a record.  We do this because we can only do
    //streams out of a record and not out of the view.
    nr = MsiViewFetch(hBinaryView, &hBinaryRecord);

//Make sure that the entry was found in the table
if (nr == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{

    //Build the path to write the file to
    TCHAR FileName [MAX_PATH] = {"somefile.ext"}; 
    char bStream [4096] = {0};
    BOOL bOkay=TRUE;

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(FileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, 
                        CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        nr = -1;
    else
    {
        long nTotal = 0;            
        long nattr = 0;
        DWORD nWritten, nBuffer;
        do
        {   // Read the stream into a buffer, 1023 bytes at a time
            nBuffer=1023;
            nr = MsiRecordReadStream(hBinaryRecord, 2, bStream, &nBuffer); // Binary & cab are 2
            if ((ERROR_SUCCESS == nr) && (nBuffer > 0))
            {
                //Write the buffer to a file. 
                nr = WriteFile(hFile, bStream, nBuffer, &nWritten, NULL);

                if (nr != 0)// 0 is bad
                    nTotal = nTotal + nBuffer; // debug only
                else
                    bOkay = FALSE;
            }
            else
            if (nr != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                bOkay = FALSE;
        } // record record stream
        while (bOkay == TRUE && (nBuffer > 0));

        // done copying file
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        }// create file

    // we only needed one row, so close the view
    MsiViewClose(hBinaryView);

    // done with query
    MsiCloseHandle(hBinaryRecord);
}

// done with binary table
MsiCloseHandle(hBinaryView);
// done with MSI database
MsiCloseHandle(hDatabase);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of how to extract every binary data entry embedded in Binary table of msi.
The original file name is lost, but the name column of the embedded data is used as the name of output file.

In my case selecting flag 'msiReadStreamAnsi' extracted exactly the same file as was embedded, but there are also other flags:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/record-readstream

```
function Get-Property ($Object, $PropertyName, [object[]]$ArgumentList) {
  return $Object.GetType().InvokeMember($PropertyName, 'Public, Instance, GetProperty', $null, $Object, $ArgumentList)
}

function Invoke-Method ($Object, $MethodName, $ArgumentList) {
  return $Object.GetType().InvokeMember($MethodName, 'Public, Instance, InvokeMethod', $null, $Object, $ArgumentList)
}

$msiPath = 'X:\install\setup.msi' # FULL PATH TO MSI*
$msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly = 0
$Installer = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer

$Database = Invoke-Method $Installer OpenDatabase @($msiPath, $msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly)

$ViewTableBinary = Invoke-Method $Database OpenView @("SELECT Name FROM _Tables WHERE Name='Binary'")
Invoke-Method $ViewTableBinary Execute
$TableBinary = Invoke-Method $ViewTableBinary Fetch
Invoke-Method $ViewTableBinary Close @()
if ($TableBinary) {
  $msiReadStreamAnsi = 2
  $ViewBinary = Invoke-Method $Database OpenView @("SELECT Name, Data FROM Binary")
  Invoke-Method $ViewBinary Execute
  Do {
    $Binary = Invoke-Method $ViewBinary Fetch
    if ($Binary) {
      $Name = Get-Property $Binary StringData 1
      $DataSize = Get-Property $Binary DataSize 2
      Write-Output "Found Binary: $msiPath/$Name ($DataSize bytes)"
      $BinaryData = Invoke-Method $Binary ReadStream @(2, $DataSize, $msiReadStreamAnsi)
      $BinaryData | Set-Content -NoNewLine $Name
    }
  }
  While ($Binary)
  Invoke-Method $ViewBinary Close @()
  Remove-Variable -Name Binary, ViewBinary
}  
Remove-Variable -Name TableBinary, ViewTableBinary, Database, Installer
```

* Full path to msi file is required, otherwise one can get an exception:

```
Exception calling "InvokeMember" with "5" argument(s): "OpenDatabase,DatabasePath,OpenMode"
```